# Looped vs Bulk arithmetic

Tags: python, for-loop

I am having some trouble with my for loops in python. My goal is to loop through a set of data and perform arithmetic on each element. Here is an example

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[6.3, 7.4, 4.2], [2.6, 7.8, 9.1], [1.7, 3.9, 6.4]])
A = B = np.zeros((len(X), len(X)))

# Method One
for i in range(len(X)):
    for j in range(len(X)):
        A[i][j] = X[i][j] + 2 * 5
        B[i][j] = X[i][j] + 8

# Method Two
A2 = X + 2 * 5
B2 = X + 8

print "A"
print A
print A2
print A == A2
print "B"
print B
print B2
print B == B2
```

Method One:
the thought here is that I would loop
through each element

Method Two:
this way it could all be done at once

The reason I don't just use method two is that for certain values I want to do different operations, so my thought was use a for loop and check each value before doing the operation. I am just very confused why these two methods yield different results.

If I switch line 9/10 then the results
are flipped.

Comment: What do you mean by line 11/12? The 11th and 12th line is a blank line and "# Method Two".

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. If you switch the order of operations done in the for-loop the answer changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line doesn't make two separate arrays `A` and `B`, it makes one array and makes two names, `A`, and `B`, refer to that array:

```
A = B = np.zeros((len(X), len(X)))
```

For example:

```
>>> A = B = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> A is B
True
>>> A[0,0] = 99
>>> A
array([[ 99.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.]])
>>> B
array([[ 99.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

Accordingly, in these lines:

```
    A[i][j] = X[i][j] + 2 * 5
    B[i][j] = X[i][j] + 8
```

you could just as well have written

```
    A[i][j] = X[i][j] + 2 * 5
    A[i][j] = X[i][j] + 8
```

which is why the order matters; they're both setting the same cell of the same array, and so the last one is the one you see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two arrays: instead of

```
A = B = np.zeros((len(X), len(X)))
```

do

```
A = np.zeros((len(X), len(X)))
B = np.zeros((len(X), len(X)))
```

You are creating two variables which point to the same object - so whatever the last thing you did, that's what you get... In Python, the expression

```
A = B
```

means "from now on, when I say 'A' I really mean 'B'".  Confusing when you come from, say, Matlab...